# MVC 3: display vallidation message instead of "Server Error in '/' Application"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, validation, server-error

I build a site where people can comment.
It works fine. but the problem is if an input is missing, it displays the "server error page" with detail. But for users, i want to show rather the validation message. (for eg:- Name is required).
How can I do it?

> Model

```
public class Feedback
{
    public int FeedbackID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Name is required")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Today's date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]        
    public DateTime AddedAt { get; set; }

    [Required (ErrorMessage="Message is required")]
    public string FeedbackMgs { get; set; }
}

public class FeedbackDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Feedback> Feedbacks { get; set; }
}
```

> Controller

```
private FeedbackDBContext FeedbackDB = new FeedbackDBContext();

    //
    // GET: /Feeback/

    public ActionResult Feedback()
    {            
        FeedbackEntries model = new FeedbackEntries();
        model.Entries = FeedbackDB.Feedbacks.ToList();

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Feedback (FeedbackEntries fd_model)
    {
        FeedbackDB.Feedbacks.Add(fd_model.Entry);
        FeedbackDB.SaveChanges();

        fd_model.Entries = FeedbackDB.Feedbacks.ToList();
        return View(fd_model);
    }
```

Comment: Enable client validation first, Second check that model is valid in the POST Feedback action and return errors in ModelState.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to:

a) Enable client side validation - see here for details/options http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html

b)  Check to see if modelstate is valid prior to saving on the server side:

```
[HttpPost] 
    public ActionResult Feedback (FeedbackEntries fd_model) 
    { 
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           FeedbackDB.Feedbacks.Add(fd_model.Entry); 
           FeedbackDB.SaveChanges(); 

           fd_model.Entries = FeedbackDB.Feedbacks.ToList(); 

        }

        return View(fd_model);
    }
```